# Why string shows the behavior of value type, but it is reference type in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am little confuse about string. I know it's reference type but when i tried, it shows the behavior of value type. I tried this:

```
String a = "abc";

String b = a;

b="xyz";

//When i print both a and b

a is abc
b is xyz
```

I was expecting both a and b print as xyz. Because they are reference type.
After that, i made a function

```
public static void change(string a)
{
    a="hello";
}
//In main i did this.

String a="abc";

Change(a);
```

I thought a will print as "hello" because it is refrence type but it still shows abc. If it is refrence type then why it behave like valu type?

Comment: In your examples I don't see string behaves like value types, it exactly behaves like reference types.

Comment: In reference type, when you copy one type to another then change in one effect on another object

Comment: string is immutable.....

Comment: `Foo a = new Foo();  Foo b = a;  b = new Foo();` my code is essentially the same as your example. `string` behaves exactly the same as my class `Foo`.